# Регулярное выражение - разбиение строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

Какое необходимо регулярное выражение для такого задания:

есть строка "stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4" - название файла
необходимо разделить на две части:

1 - stroenie-15-k-1

2 - cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4

Я предполагаю, это делается командой sed, или какой-либо другой?
И какое регулярное выражение будет соответствовать этим 2-м вариантам.

Comment: Делается командой `sed` или `awk`. Чтобы помочь с регуляркой нужно понимать принцип разделения строки, вариантов много: по 4-му `-`, по минусу перед `cam`, по минусу перед словом, которое перед чем-то, похожим на дату и т.д.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

примеры разбиения **данной конкретной** строки:

```
$ echo 'stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4' | sed -r 's/(.{15}).(.*)/\1\n\2/'
stroenie-15-k-1
cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4
$ echo 'stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4' | sed -r 's/(.*).(cam.*)/\1\n\2/'
stroenie-15-k-1
cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4
$ echo 'stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4' | sed -r 's/(.*k-1).(.*)/\1\n\2/'
stroenie-15-k-1
cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4
$ echo 'stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4' | sed -r 's/(.*-1)-(.*)/\1\n\2/'
stroenie-15-k-1
cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4
$ echo 'stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4' | sed -r 's/(.*[0-9])-([^0-9].*)/\1\n\2/'
stroenie-15-k-1
cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4
```

как видите, все регулярные выражения отличаются.
и так можно продолжать (практически) до бесконечности.

---

к слову:

*bash* и *sed* — это две совершенно разные программы. у каждой из них есть свой собственный внутренний язык. я не силён в теории и могу ошибиться, но, вроде бы, и тот и другой — тьюринг-полные. а, значит, и на том и на другом можно разбить любую строку на любое количество частей по любым правилам.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему последний пример не режет по `15-k`. Ааа, понял...

Comment: @andy.37, потому что раньше `[0-9]` стоит «жадный» квантификатор `*`.

Comment: Да, уже сам допер). А можно ли в sed сделать нежадный поиск?

Comment: @andy.37, насколько я знаю, ни в одной из популярных реализаций программы sed нет не-жадных (non-greedy) квантификаторов.

Comment: `echo 'stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4' | sed -r 's/(.?[0-9])-([^0-9].*)/\1\n\2/'`, хотя это не то... Я тоже не могу найти. На stackowerflow.com пишут, что sed только жадный.

Comment: @JocBro1, задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос, нажав кнопку в правом верхнем углу страницы. если необходим контекст, можете дать ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4" |  perl -slane '<>; chomp; if (/^(.+)(?=-cam)-(.+)$/) {print "$1\n$2";}'
```

Это если разбивать по `-cam`

```
echo "stroenie-15-k-1-cam-2015-10-10_22-00.mp4" |  sed -r 's/^(.+)-cam(.+)$/\1\ncam\2/'
```